# How to configure Django to use Heroku Dev Postgre while local?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm trying to configure local dev environment with Heroku, Django and virtualenv. Everything seems to be working when pushed to Heroku hosting, but locally, I cannot seem to connect to the Heroku-supplied dev Postgre DB.

According to the instructions, I added the following to settings.py:

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()
```

But this doesn't seem to get invoked while running locally. Get the following exception:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

Is it even possible to connect to the Heroku hosted dev Postgre from a local instance of Django? If it is, what am I missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out to be relatively straightforward...

dj_database_url.cofig() takes a parameter default. Database info on heroku can be found here:
https://postgres.heroku.com/databases/

If your db info and credentials are as follows:
Host    somehost.amazonaws.com
Database    somedb
User    foo
Port    5432
Password    bar

Then the settings.py entry should look like this:

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://foo:bar@somehost.amazonaws.com:5432/somedb')
```

Same steps work if you are using a local Postgre setup as well.

Comment: Instead of hardcoding URLs, why don't you use [config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).  That's effectively what's happening when you run on Heroku - a DATABASE_URL variable is made available, pointing to the database.  You should simply do the same locally - setting your DATABASE_URL to the appropriate value.  Then your code doesn't change - which is *much* better.  This is all made easier if you are using Foreman from the Heroku Toolbelt.  Just create a local .env file with the local config vars when running locally.

Comment: Awesome, would you mind posting this (+ instructions on how to do this) as an answer, and I'll accept it. Thank you!